# how to convert .docx file to html using python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import mammoth

f = open("D:\filename.docx", 'rb')
document = mammoth.convert_to_html(f)
```

I am unable to get a .html file while i run this code,please help me to get it, When i converted to .html file i am not getting images inserted into word file into .html file,Can you please help me how to get images into .html from .docx?

Comment: You haven’t told us what error you’re experiencing.

Comment: I didn't got error but i was not getting .html file after converting

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
import mammoth

f = open("path_to_file.docx", 'rb')
b = open('filename.html', 'wb')
document = mammoth.convert_to_html(f)
b.write(document.value.encode('utf8'))
f.close()
b.close()
```

Comment: unable to convert docx with chart ! what to do ?

Answer (score 4):

This is may be late to answer this question but just incase if someone still looking for the answer where word "tables/images/" should remains same after conversion to html below answer would help.

```
import win32com.client as win32
# Open MS Word
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

wordFilePath = "C:\filename.docx"

doc = word.Documents.Open(wordFilePath)
# change to a .html
txt_path = wordFilePath.split('.')[0] + '.html'

# wdFormatFilteredHTML has value 10
# saves the doc as an html
doc.SaveAs(txt_path, 10)

doc.Close()
# noinspection PyBroadException
try:
    word.ActiveDocument()
except Exception:
    word.Quit()
```

Comment: Hi snehil singh,  Is it possible to convert to HTML but also keeping any images embedded into the HTML file instead of being linked with an external folder?

Comment: @sugarakis Did tried above code ? this code will keep your images in HTML file.
Please post a question with your detailed query and challenges you are facing provide me a link

Comment: Hi snehil singh, the above code creates the HTML with all its format and images, but it also creates a separate folder with the same name as the DOCX file, where the images are  located. If I rename the HTML file or delete the extra folder, any images in the HTML file are not shown. I would like a solution where the HTML file by itself can display any images as well. Thank you

Comment: Hi @sugarakis you can use a Python library like BeautifulSoup to modify the image references in the HTML file to embed the images directly in the file. If you need complete code Please post a question and provide me a link

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try the following code

```
    import mammoth
    with open("document.docx", "rb") as docx_file:
    result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
    html = result.value
```

Comment: But i am unable to convert the images from .docx file to .html file,Can you please help me how to do that?