# python - How to extract the text of DOCX hyperlinks?

Tags: python, docx

Building on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475757/how-to-extract-the-url-in-hyperlinks-from-a-docx-file-using-python):

```
from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

document = Document('test.docx')
rels = document.part.rels

def iter_hyperlink_rels(rels):
    for rel in rels:
        if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
            yield rels[rel]._target      

print(iter_hyperlink_rels(rels)
```

I need to get both the url **and** the text of the hyperlink (e.g. `mydomain.com` for the url and `Go to My Domain` for the text)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I had to go via `html` to do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('my_word_file.htm', 'r') as file:
    page = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

text_and_url = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    text_and_url.append({'text':link.string, 'url':link.get('href')})
```

---

Foor conversion of `docx` file `html`:

[how to convert .docx file to html using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008593/how-to-convert-docx-file-to-html-using-python)